# Order of event handler registration calls and mongoose.connect() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Does it matter if the function `mongoose.connect(URI)` is called before or after the registration of the event handler callback functions?
My thought is that if `connect()` is called before the registration of the callbacks, the events like 'connected' may be fired before its callback has been registered and thus go unprocessed. I am not sure however, and it's difficult to test for me.
Links to the relevant mongoose or JavaScript documentation welcome.

Example:

```
mongoose.connect(dbURI, options);

// When successfully connected
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
  console.log('Mongoose default connection to ' + dbURI + ' opened');
});
```

versus

```
// When successfully connected
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
  console.log('Mongoose default connection to ' + dbURI + ' opened');
});

mongoose.connect(dbURI, options);
```